# CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported after upgrading to .net 4

Tags: c#-4.0, globalization, cultureinfo

We set the culture to a custom culture using CultureInfo(customCulture)

We create the customCulture in the global.cs in app_start just in case.

On my local PC this works fine.
However on the web server, when I go to set the culture, I get the error that the culture is not supported? 
I've checked the Windows\Globalization folder and there is a culture file there for the correct culture?

The same code worked fine under 3.5?

Comment: lol thanks! Any helpful advice :) ?
Its preventing us switching to a custom culture which means we can't go live with our upgrade to .Net 4.0 as half our client base uses the custom culture so we can present different strings out of our resx files

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else gets this issue, I had to write a command line tool to deregister the culture and then re-register it.

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Globalization;

    namespace InstallCulture
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Is CustomCulture already installed?
                string parentCultureName = "en-GB";
                string extendedName = "custom";
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo[] userCultures = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("number of user cultures:{0}", userCultures.Count()));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Setting culture {0}-{1}", parentCultureName, extendedName));
                // Install CustomCulture based on language parent.
                System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder builder = new System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(
                        string.Format("{0}-{1}", parentCultureName, extendedName),
                        System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

                builder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));
                builder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new System.Globalization.RegionInfo("GB"));
                Console.WriteLine("CultureName:. . . . . . . . . . {0}", builder.CultureName);
                Console.WriteLine("CultureEnglishName: . . . . . . {0}", builder.CultureEnglishName);
                Console.WriteLine("CultureNativeName:. . . . . . . {0}", builder.CultureNativeName);

                foreach(System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultInfo in userCultures)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found culture in userCultures");
                    if(cultInfo.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}-{1}", parentCultureName, extendedName).ToLower())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} already registered", cultInfo.Name));
                        CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister("en-GB-custom");
                        Console.WriteLine("Unregistered culture en-GB-custom");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Registering culture en-GB-PolHol");
                builder.Register();
                Console.WriteLine("Create new culture info object");
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB-custom");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: . . . . . . . . . . . . . {0}", culture.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("EnglishName:. . . . . . . . . . {0}", culture.EnglishName);
                Console.WriteLine("NativeName: . . . . . . . . . . {0}", culture.NativeName);
                Console.WriteLine("Set threads to new culture");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
                Console.WriteLine("Set culture done");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the numerous guides of how to add a custom culture and on local machine if worked perfectly. However, I got CultureNotFoundException on the CultureInfo constructor on a development server with error on the name. The nlp file was created correctly and I suspect the registry step was the issue, but I couldn't find any resource about it. More over, it corrupted any other language mapping on the machine for all other applications.

Eventually I followed the The Developer's Guide to Building Global Windows and Web Applications: Chapter 11 - Custom Cultures on codeproject and replaced an existing culture with the needed modifications, which works correctly.

Still I wonder why my original custom culture didn't work and the replacement did. In any case I also wanted to share my experience.

Comment: Can you post the link to the CodeProject's page? Thanks